# Strange behavior in app that wont play sound unless a Toast line is inserted

Tags: java, android, audio

So I'm making a xylophone app and it weirdly works(plays sound) only when inserted a seemingly unimportant line which Toasts the loaded soundID and I'm not sure what to make of it.If you remove the Toast line the onClick function wont play sound at all.
The aforementioned line is in the onClick function within the for loop

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Helpful Constants
private final int NR_OF_SIMULTANEOUS_SOUNDS = 7;
private final float LEFT_VOLUME = 1.0f;
private final float RIGHT_VOLUME = 1.0f;
private final int NO_LOOP = 0;
private final int PRIORITY = 0;
private final float NORMAL_PLAY_RATE = 1.0f;

//Adding IDs here
int[] xyloIDs =
        {
            R.id.c_key,
            R.id.d_key,
            R.id.e_key,
            R.id.f_key,
            R.id.g_key,
            R.id.a_key,
            R.id.b_key,
        };
int[] soundIDs =
        {
                R.raw.note1_c,
                R.raw.note2_d,
                R.raw.note3_e,
                R.raw.note4_f,
                R.raw.note5_g,
                R.raw.note6_a,
                R.raw.note7_b,
        };

private SoundPool mSoundPool;
private int mSoundId;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Creating a new SoundPool
    mSoundPool = new SoundPool(NR_OF_SIMULTANEOUS_SOUNDS, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

}


public void onClick(View view)
{
    for(int i=0; i < xyloIDs.length ; i++ )
    {
        if(view.getId() == xyloIDs[i]) {
            //Load and get the IDs to identify the sounds
            mSoundId = mSoundPool.load(this, soundIDs[i], 1);
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(mSoundId) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mSoundPool.play(mSoundId, LEFT_VOLUME, RIGHT_VOLUME, PRIORITY, NO_LOOP, NORMAL_PLAY_RATE);
        }
    }

}
```

And here is my activity_main.xml if it makes any difference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.londonappbrewery.xylophonepm.MainActivity">

<Button
    style="@style/KeyStyle"
    android:id="@+id/c_key"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>

<Button
    style="@style/KeyStyle"
    android:id="@+id/d_key"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    />


<Button
    style="@style/KeyStyle"
    android:id="@+id/e_key"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    />

<Button
    style="@style/KeyStyle"
    android:id="@+id/f_key"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    />

<Button
    style="@style/KeyStyle"
    android:id="@+id/g_key"
    android:background="@color/turquoise"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    />


<Button
    style="@style/KeyStyle"
    android:id="@+id/a_key"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    />

<Button
    style="@style/KeyStyle"
    android:id="@+id/b_key"
    android:background="@color/purple"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    />
```

Comment: What Android API are you using ? The constructor was deprecated in API21 in favor of  SoundPool.Builder https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#SoundPool(int,%20int,%20int), maybe there is a relation :)

Comment: Was using API25, tried it on API20, doesnt make any difference,really strange :D @w00ly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your file on loading so it can not be play,
the Toasts make your load and play delay more.

You may need implement setOnLoadCompleteListener and call the play inside the listener.

```
mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener()
 {
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,int status) {
mSoundPool.play(sampleId, LEFT_VOLUME, RIGHT_VOLUME, PRIORITY, NO_LOOP, NORMAL_PLAY_RATE);

 }
 });
```